# Get the EncodedURl of the document added to a Document Set through Client Object Model

Tags: document-set

I refer several blogs for this issue , they said there will be a column named as `EncodedAbsUrl` for the document set but I can't find that column.

How can I get the URI to the document?

Answer (score 1):

With client object model use :

```
string server = site Url ;
            var context = new ClientContext(server);
            var web = context.Web;
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("text");
            ListItemCollection objListItemCollection = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
            context.Load(objListItemCollection,
items => items.Include(item => item.Id,
item => item["FileLeafRef"],
item => item["LinkFilename"],
item => item["FileRef"],
item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"],
item => item["DocIcon"]));

            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach(ListItem item in objListItemCollection)
            {
                string fileUrl = item["EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();

            }
```

You can modify the code as per your requirement.

You can get the absolute URL with the following code in server object model

```
SPListItem item = your item;
string absUrl = (string) item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];
```

For SPFile object:

```
SPFile file = your file object;
 string absUrl = (string) file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];
```

Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216832/how-to-get-the-absolute-url-of-a-file-in-sharepoint-library

Comment: using Client object model C# code i required that url.

Comment: I am having a requirement to retrieve the document(excel doc) from the Document lib and convert it into pdf format, for that i am having the conversion code but requires the absUrl of the document.

Comment: I have added the code with CSOM also. Please verfiy.

Comment: item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"] is not available in the listItem

Comment: this is code is working fine for me. Which version are you using? You can check other properties also.